# Understanding the Q-learning loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, loss-functions, q-learning

Perhaps this can be explained a little more to me. I understand what's in literature but I'm struggling to understand why this is the preferred loss.

If we have an agent that can move ↑↓→← and for instance chooses to move in the direction that's correct. say the reward is two steps to the left and the highest observed Q values are both left, left then why have these states regress? The max Q value will never be reached. $Q(s,a) = r + \gamma \max_{a'\in A}Q(s',a')$ This is never true because the updated $Q(s,a)$ in the direction chosen will never equal but tend towards $r + \gamma \max_{a'\in A}Q(s',a')$

Since the method of getting our value $Q(s, a)$ is

$$Q(s,a) = (1-\alpha)Q(s,a)-\alpha(r + \gamma \max_{a'\in A}Q(s',a'))$$

I also see an unfortunate consequence of using this as our loss. If we move in a direction of no reward and then say lose and score a negative reward, so death/failure is all that awaits our agent down the chosen path. Then won't this movement see no loss as

$$Q(s,a) = r + \gamma \max_{a'\in A}Q(s',a')$$
since
$$0 = 0 + 1 \times 0 \therefore Q(s,a) = r + \gamma \max_{a'\in A}Q(s',a')$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know how my thinking was wrong and I'll give a quick explanation for what's happening.

If you understand how the Q learning loss works, I think my question would have only confused you.

Basically, the Q values are both derived from your nueral network (NN). $Q(s',a')$ is also derived with the NN but the gradient isn't saved. This is important as you're correcting $Q(s,a)$ and not $(r+\gamma max_{a \in A}Q(s',a'))$.

Then its as simple as following the formula. the $Q(s,a)$ value associated with the action and the max of $Q(s',a')$ is taken and input into our loss.

I hope this helps